# Swift 4: Can an object remove itself from a collection

Tags: swift

Here is pseudocode for what I want to achieve:

```
let a = AClass()
let go = NSMutableArray()
go.add(a)
.
.
.
class AClass{
  .
  .
  .
  fileprivate func removeMyselfFromCollection() { //Called from within the class
    //TODO: How to remove myself from the collection I am in.        
  }
}
```

It could be any collection, array or dictionary etc. Something similar to `removeFromSuperview()`

**Update: Responding to a common question...**

Question: Why I need this?

Answer:  Scenario is a bit complex but bringing it down to most basic details. I am uploading files (audio, video, sound) to remote storage. Once files are uploaded, I have a mechanism (listeners) to know when my files are there, I don't need local objects to tell me the status. I add local objects to a global collection to keep them alive till the files are uploading (one object representing each file). Each object takes care of each file being uploaded. I wish that each of my objects removes itself silently from the global collection once upload is finished (reason explained above).

Comment: You _can_ do it. But the question is _should_ you?

Comment: For the same reasons we have removeFromSuperview()

Comment: Sorry for the snarky comment. My point is that one can do this, but you’d only contemplate it in very particular cases. You give `removerFromSuperview` example, but that’s not just some general collection, but rather a recursive tree structure where each node keeps reference to its children (and each child node keeps a weak reference to its respective parent node). But as a general design, having a member manipulate the collection of which it is belongs is highly suspect. But if you have a particular scenario in mind (like the recursive tree structure), then maybe it starts to make sense.

Comment: Hey @Rob please see the edited question, the scenario.

Comment: There are many valid examples, a typical valid use case is when that collection is a singleton (or a singleton-like), e.g. `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)`.

Comment: @Sulthan - Sure, you could implement `func removeMyselfAsObserver() { NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)}` but applying that here, a singleton for his "global collection" would be questionable, IMHO. I'm not crazy about Burak's suggestion of giving the uploaded object a reference to the collection as that seems to needlessly coupling objects. I'd be inclined for the uploader to be maintaining this collection of pending uploads, and it just updates this collection as uploads finish. The other traditional approach would be some custom notification as upload states change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless you:

a. Implement this method yourself.

b. Pass the collection in as a parameter.

c. Have the object's method forward the `remove(self)` message to the collection.

Given that you would have to just forward the message to the collection anyway, and you'd have to know the collection at the time you called the method, there's no value in such a method. It adds complexity without adding any value.

Another problem is that objects can be members of more than one collection. What should happen in that case? Should it be removed from all the collections it belongs to? The first one to which it was added? The last? And how would you track that?

All in all, this seems like a all-pain-no-gain proposition.

Comment: How removeFromSuperview() works, any insights? It actually simplifies your code. And yes, like an instance of a view can be added only once in a view hierarchy, in my case the object should not be part of more than one collections.

Comment: If no other solid mechanism is there, I like the idea of passing collection as a parameter you described.

Comment: But why do this in the first place? It adds complexity without really adding any value.

Comment: Hey Duncan, Please see my updated question, explaining the scenario I am considering.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by typing your own custom insertion method into the extension of NSMutableArray, and in this method, you can assign the array to the object variable.

```
class SomeClass {
    var containedBy: NSMutableArray?
    var value: String

    init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func removeFromCollection() -> Void {
        guard let containedBy = self.containedBy else { return }
        containedBy.remove(self)
    }
}


extension NSMutableArray{
    func addRemovable(value: SomeClass)  {
        value.containedBy = self
        self.add(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you went this way you should use generics and protocol conformance (create a `Containable` protocol, and have the array support any object that conforms to the `Containable` protocol.) Again, though, this whole thing seems like a bad idea.